# How can I sync over the internet in an Android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud, chat

Writing my first Android app here...

A part of the app is syncing messages across all devices with the app. A stream of sorts.

I was thinking of adding each message to an SQLite database and then syncing that over Google App Engine. Would that work? Is there a better way? I've heard of XMPP as well, but I'd prefer avoiding paying for a server until necessary.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. There are many, many ways to accomplish the effect of "syncing". The "right" or "best" way is highly situational and/or subjective.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [Google iosched app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/09/conference-data-sync-gcm-google-io.html) for some android best practices on data sync via cloud.

you probably need to consider offline scenario too, as this is common in mobile devices.

another option is to consider third party services like https://parse.com/, or https://www.firebase.com/